# How to change pivot header into page number?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a pivot control, the items are binded from a list, I want to make the pivot header look like a page number, look like this : (1/20) (2/20) (3/20) .... This is my xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/PivotBackground.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <controls:Pivot x:Name="newsPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding LatestArticles}" Margin="0,68,0,0">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="1" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Grid.Row="1"   
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Width="425"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding thumbnail, StringFormat='http://digitaledition.philstar.com/newsrepository/newsarticles/thumbs/images/\{0\}'}" 
                                   Margin="18,100,0,0"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="2"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Width="150" 
                                   Height="175"  
                                   Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding author, StringFormat='By \{0\}'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Width="220"
                                   Foreground="Gray"
                                   Margin="120,135,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateFormatted}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Width="240"
                                   Foreground="Gray"
                                   Margin="140,210,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Width="425"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   Margin="10,325,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <!--Pivot item two-->
        </controls:Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

Spent hours of searching on google but no solution found. Please someone help me with my project. thanks in advance!

Code behind Xaml:

```
public NewsPivot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            var y = new WebClient();
            Observable
              .FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(y, "DownloadStringCompleted")
              .Subscribe(r =>
              {
                  var des =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LatestArticles>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
                  newsPivot.ItemsSource = des.Where(s=> s.category_id == "1");
              });
            y.DownloadStringAsync(
              new Uri("http://sample.json.com/mobile/articles?"));
        }
```

LatestArticle.cs :

```
public class LatestArticles
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string hits { get; set; }
        public string thumbCaption { get; set; }
        public string category_id { get; set; }
        public string dateFormatted { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do not bind the ItemsSource as you are overriding it in code behind

Answer (score 0):

You would have to Bind the Text of the Header to a property on your Articles object. This propery would be the page index of the article.

```
<controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageNumber}" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

You would then need to set the page number of the Article when it is added to the LatestArticles collection.

```
LatestArticles.Add(article);
article.PageNumber = LatestArticles.Count +1;
```

Another option is to use a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). This option would require you to have access to the LatestArticles somehow.

```
<controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PageNumberConverter}}" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

The ValueConverter is very simple

```
public class PageNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Assumes that the App.xaml.cs class has a static ViewModel property
        return App.ViewModel.LatestArticles.IndexOf(value) + 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ShawnKendrot, my Latestarticles is a class where my json data are stored. How will I do that in PageNumberCoverter class?

Comment: You would need to have a ViewModel that can be accessed from anywhere in your application. If you create a new "Data Bound Application" in Visual Studio you will see this example. Your ItemsSource for the Pivot would bind to a property on the ViewModel and your code behind would set the property of the ViewModel rather than set the ItemsSource.